# How to generate @page with loop in less

Tags: css, less

I am not familiar with complex script in less but, I search to use a loop in order to create the following CSS:

```css
@page page_00_recto {
 ....
 size: A4
 margin-top: 00mm;
}
@page page_01_recto {
 ....
 size: A4
 margin-top: 00mm;
}
...
```

I have tried this

```css
each(range(1, 100, 1), {
  @page page_{@index}_recto {
    size: 110mm 240mm;
    margin-top: @value;
  };
});
...
```

But I obtains always this error

```
@page tab_{@index}_recto {
@index rule is missing block or ending semi-colon
```

Where is my error? thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must be using Less >3.9
2. You must escape `@` in `@page`
3. You should be using dynamically built selector

So final LESS code looks like this:

```less
each(range(1, 100, 1), {
  @selector: ~"@page page_@{index}_recto";
  
  @{selector} {
    size: 110mm 240mm;
    margin-top: @value;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. your solution completely meets my needs.